# Correct way to update an user image in the database after upload?

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried it myself and was stuck on query itself. It might not even be the query that's wrong, I'm not sure. What is the correct way to update an image if a user decides to change their profile picture?

```
    <?php
session_start();
       $msg = "";
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $target = "img/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
        $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET image='$images' WHERE username='$username'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $msg = echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        header("Location: profile.php?uploadsuccess");
    } else {
        $msg = "There Was A problem uploading image";
    }
}
?>




    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `images` varchar(200) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting success, but it's not updating the field in the database

Comment: What is the data type of your image field?

Comment: I added the structure in the question

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upload an actual image to a field that will only hold 200 characters. Take a look at your structure, what you need to do is save the image to whatever directory is configured for that purpose and only save the name (and possibly path) of that image to the `image` field in your database.

Comment: You don't have an `image` column in your `users` table, you have `images`.  Follow his instructions and research mysqli prepared statements with placeholders for improved security.